# Possible to do Azure RBAC Role Assignment for ACR Repository?

Tags: azure, azure-container-registry, azure-rbac, acr

I was hoping to be able to create an RBAC role assignment for specific repository in an Azure Container Registry but I can only find the resource ID/scope to create a role assignment for the entire ACR.

Is there a way to do this or find the information I need? Or a way to lookup all the resources/scopes within an azure resource that I could create an rbac role assignment against (which would apply to this and other resources in general)?

I'm just wanting to let a group of users have permissions to a specific repository in an ACR and not sure if I'm just overlooking something or if its not actually possible.

NOTE: I saw some token way to do it but I'm just wanting to do it with rbac role assignment to the repository resource and add the users to the role assignment and be done with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, as of November 2021 it is still impossible but there is a task for this on Azure ACR team backlog. Please find the [task link](https://github.com/Azure/acr/issues/380). So only way that you can follow right now is   [repository scoped permissions with token](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/azure/container-registry/container-registry-repository-scoped-permissions)